# how to fix a mesh shattering when bending bones slighly?

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones

why is the hand sniff like this, although that i am not moving the bones unnaturally:
[image: The result]

i used weighting but it doesn't work:[image]

How to fix this mesh, and thanks in advance <3

Comment: Maybe try in Edit mode to select all and M > Merge by Distance

Comment: it worked tysm, but the mesh is kinda curving

Comment: what do you mean by curving? please show some screenshots, maybe you need to reparent...

Comment: ok i got it, i think bec. the merge by distance decreased my mesh vertices so it looked semi-low poly, but i just subdivide it in the edit mode ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your faces are separate, switch to *Edit* mode, select all and <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*.